# BillingClient.BillingClientStateListener.onBillingSetupFinished is called multiple times

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-billing, play-billing-library

I tried to write a wrapper for BillingClient v.2.2.0 with Kotlin Coroutines:

```
package com.cantalk.photopose.billing

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import com.android.billingclient.api.*
import com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClient.*
import com.cantalk.photopose.util.Logger
import kotlinx.coroutines.CompletableDeferred
import kotlin.coroutines.resume
import kotlin.coroutines.resumeWithException
import kotlin.coroutines.suspendCoroutine

class BillingClientAsync(context: Context) {
    private val billingClient: BillingClient = setupBillingClient(context)
    private val pendingPurchaseFlows = HashMap<String, CompletableDeferred<Purchase>>()

    private fun setupBillingClient(context: Context): BillingClient {
        return newBuilder(context)
            .enablePendingPurchases()
            .setListener { billingResult, purchases ->
                if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingResponseCode.OK && purchases != null) {
                    for (purchase in purchases) {
                        val deferred = pendingPurchaseFlows.remove(purchase.sku)
                        deferred?.complete(purchase)
                    }
                } else {
                    val iterator = pendingPurchaseFlows.iterator()
                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        val entry = iterator.next()
                        entry.value.completeExceptionally(BillingException(billingResult))
                        iterator.remove()
                    }
                }
            }
            .build()
    }

    suspend fun queryPurchases(): List<Purchase> {
        Logger.debug("query purchases")

        ensureConnected()
        val queryPurchases = billingClient.queryPurchases(SkuType.INAPP)
        if (queryPurchases.responseCode == BillingResponseCode.OK) {
            return queryPurchases.purchasesList
        } else {
            throw BillingException(queryPurchases.billingResult)
        }
    }

    suspend fun querySkuDetails(@SkuType type: String, skus: List<String>): List<SkuDetails> {
        Logger.debug("query sku details for", type)

        ensureConnected()
        return suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
            val params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                .setType(type)
                .setSkusList(skus)
                .build()
            billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params) { billingResult, skuDetailsList ->
                if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    continuation.resume(skuDetailsList)
                } else {
                    continuation.resumeWithException(BillingException(billingResult))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    suspend fun purchase(activity: Activity, skuDetails: SkuDetails): Purchase {
        Logger.debug("purchase", skuDetails.sku)

        ensureConnected()
        val currentPurchaseFlow = CompletableDeferred<Purchase>()
            .also { pendingPurchaseFlows[skuDetails.sku] = it }
        val params = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
            .setSkuDetails(skuDetails)
            .build()
        billingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, params)
        return currentPurchaseFlow.await()
    }

    suspend fun consume(purchase: Purchase): String {
        Logger.debug("consume", purchase.sku)

        ensureConnected()
        return suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
            val params = ConsumeParams.newBuilder()
                .setPurchaseToken(purchase.purchaseToken)
                .setDeveloperPayload("TBD")
                .build()
            billingClient.consumeAsync(params) { billingResult, purchaseToken ->
                if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    continuation.resume(purchaseToken)
                } else {
                    continuation.resumeWithException(BillingException(billingResult))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    suspend fun acknowledgePurchase(purchase: Purchase) {
        Logger.debug("acknowledge", purchase.sku)

        ensureConnected()
        return suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
            val params = AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                .setPurchaseToken(purchase.purchaseToken)
                .setDeveloperPayload("TBD")
                .build()
            billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(params) { billingResult ->
                if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    continuation.resume(Unit)
                } else {
                    continuation.resumeWithException(BillingException(billingResult))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun ensureConnected() {
        if (!billingClient.isReady) {
            startConnection()
        }
    }

    private suspend fun startConnection() {
        Logger.debug("connect to billing service")

        return suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
            billingClient.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
                override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
                    if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                        continuation.resume(Unit)
                    } else {
                        // TODO: 3 Google Play In-app Billing API version is less than 3
                        continuation.resumeWithException(BillingException(billingResult))
                    }
                }

                override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() = Unit
            })
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, when I try to query purchases or purchase I ensure that client is ready. But in production there are many errors:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at kotlin.coroutines.SafeContinuation.resumeWith (SafeContinuation.java:2)
  at com.cantalk.photopose.billing.BillingClientAsync$startConnection$2$1.onBillingSetupFinished (BillingClientAsync.java:2)
  at com.android.billingclient.api.zzai.run (zzai.java:6)
```

I tried to understand what the cause of problem and got that if `BillingClientStateListener.onBillingSetupFinished` will be called multiple time there can be an exception `IllegalStateException: Already resumed`. I've wondered how is it possible, because I am creating new listener every `startConnection` call? I can't reproduce this issue on emulator or my test device. Can anybody explain me what does happen here and how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have the same issue with the latest version of billing, instead of the old 2.2.0 one? https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/release-notes

Comment: Same here, yes, latest version of everything. Same problem: unable to reproduce but users see it.

Answer (score 6):

I tried to do the same at first, but the rationale is not correct. `onBillingSetupFinished()` might be called more than once, by design. Once you call `BillingClient.startConnection(BillingClientStateListener)` with the callback, it stores the callback internally and calls it again if connection is dropped/regained. You shouldn't pass in a new object on other calls to `BillingClient.startConnection(BillingClientStateListener)`.

Read the documentation on `onBillingServiceDisconnected()`:

> Called to notify that the connection to the billing service was lost.
>
> Note: This does not remove the billing service connection itself -
> this binding to the service will remain active, and you will receive a
> call to onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult) when the billing service
> is next running and setup is complete.

This means that when the connection is dropped and then later regained, `onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult)` will be called again, and, in your implementation, you will try to resume the coroutine again, but the coroutine continuation has already been resumed and you will get an `IllegalStateException`.

What I ended up doing is implementing the `BillingClientStateListener` interface in the class itself, and on the callbacks I update a `SharedFlow<Int>` with the `BillingResult` from `onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult)`

```kotlin
private val billingClientStatus = MutableSharedFlow<Int>(
    replay = 1,
    onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST
)

override fun onBillingSetupFinished(result: BillingResult) {
    billingClientStatus.tryEmit(result.responseCode)
}

override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
    billingClientStatus.tryEmit(BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.SERVICE_DISCONNECTED)
}
```

Then, you can collect the flow to fetch your SKU prices or handle pending purchases if billing client is connected, or implement a retry logic if it isn't:

```kotlin
init {
    billingClientStatus.tryEmit(BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.SERVICE_DISCONNECTED)
    lifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
        billingClientStatus.collect {
            when (it) {
                BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK -> with (billingClient) {
                    updateSkuPrices()
                    handlePurchases()
                }
                else -> billingClient.startConnection(this)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And if you are doing some operation that requires billing client connection, you can wait for it by doing something like:

```kotlin
private suspend fun requireBillingClientSetup(): Boolean =
    withTimeoutOrNull(TIMEOUT_MILLIS) {
        billingClientStatus.first { it == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK }
        true
    } ?: false
```

(Note that I used `SharedFlow<T>` and not `StateFlow<T>` for `billingClientStatus`: the reason is `StateFlow<T>` does not support emitting consecutive equal values).

Answer (score 2):

My setup is ever so slightly different (I call back with a Boolean value) but this is the best I could come up with. More of a workaround than a real explanation:

```
private suspend fun start(): Boolean = suspendCoroutine {
  billingClient.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
    var resumed = false;

    override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
      if (!resumed) {
        it.resume(billingResult.responseCode == BillingResponseCode.OK)
        resumed = true
      }
    }

    override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
      Toast.makeText(context, R.string.pay_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
      Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Billing disconnected")
    }
  })
}
```

The jury is still out on whether it's a genuine, long term solution or not.

Comment: While seemingly elegant, this may lead to an IllegalStateException: onBillingSetupFinished() is not guaranteed to be called just once, so you might try to resume an already resumed continuation.


void onBillingServiceDisconnected ()
Called to notify that the connection to the billing service was lost.

Note: This does not remove the billing service connection itself - this binding to the service will remain active, and you will receive a call to onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult) when the billing service is next running and setup is complete.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a try catch on IllegalStateException + log...

```
val result = suspendCoroutine<Boolean> { continuation ->
    billingClient.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
        override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            WttjLogger.v("onBillingServiceDisconnected")
            // Do not call continuation resume, as per documentation
            // https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClientStateListener#onbillingservicedisconnected
        }

        override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
            val responseCode = billingResult.responseCode
            val debugMessage = billingResult.debugMessage
            if (responseCode != BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                WttjLogger.w("onBillingSetupFinished: $responseCode $debugMessage")
            } else {
                WttjLogger.v("onBillingSetupFinished: $responseCode $debugMessage")
            }
            try {
                continuation.resume(responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK)
            } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
                WttjLogger.e(e)
            }
        }
    })
}
```